# Add a script tag to internet explorer through c++

Tags: javascript, c++, com

I have a COM client executable which spawns a new IE process and grabs a reference to the IWebBrowser2 interface, and I would like to inject a JavaScript tag into the webpage that IE loads.

Currently this is what I am doing:

```
void Document::AddScript(const std::wstring script, const std::wstring id) {

HRESULT hr = S_OK;
IHTMLElement* pHtmlElem;
CComVariant vJavascript = "text/javascript";
CComBSTR vScriptContents = script.c_str();
CComBSTR vId = id.c_str();

hr = _pDocument2->createElement(_T("script"), &pHtmlElem);
if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && pHtmlElem != NULL)
{

    hr = pHtmlElem->setAttribute(_T("type"), vJavascript);
    hr = pHtmlElem->put_innerText(vScriptContents);
    hr = pHtmlElem->put_id(vId);
}

CComPtr<IHTMLElement> body;
hr = pDocument->get_body(&body);

CComQIPtr<IHTMLDOMNode, &IID_IHTMLDOMNode> spBodyNode = body; 
CComQIPtr<IHTMLDOMNode, &IID_IHTMLDOMNode> spNodeNew;
hr = pHtmlElem->QueryInterface(&spNodeNew);

CComPtr<IHTMLDOMNode> node;
if (spBodyNode)
{
    hr = spBodyNode->appendChild(spNodeNew, &node);
}


}
```

The HRESULT returned from spBodyNode->appendChild is coming back as S_OK; however, nothing is getting appended to the page. What can I do to get

```
<script id="myScript">
    function xyz(){
    //...
    }
</script>
```

onto the page?

**EDIT**

The functions added by this method need to be executable in the web page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did some quick research on the topic, and found [this article](https://ehsanakhgari.org/article/visual-c/2008-06-22/adding-html-content-webbrowser-control-dynamically) which shares a library using the IWebBrowser2 as a constructor's argument. I think it will suffice.

Also, you may try using a Browser Helper Object (seems more pratical even though does not uses that interface). Here: [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/797515/Writing-HTML-content-to-a-webpages-DOM-with-a-Cplu)

Good Luck

Comment: So what you suggested got the scripts into the browser body, but none of the functions I added were executable from the browser. I didn't realize that could be a case so I added an edit in the OP. I need the scripts to be usable from the browser.

Comment: That's a problem, for sure. If you refresh the page it's gone, right? If that's so, we have few solutions left, which may not be appliable: Adding a loop with JS in the page's header (without injecting, in the original document) that requests another script; Finding a memory in IE that executes/reads the HTML and mess with it using pointers. I'll try to think of something else.

Comment: yeah, I am not sure what I can do. I need the script tags to be referenced and executed by other script tags because they communicate with each other through events. This works just fine in Chrome and FF, but IE has to be the thorn in my side.

Comment: Have you read this? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752047(v=vs.85).aspx Idk if it's going work but surely is related.

Answer (score 0):

You can [navigate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752133(v=vs.85).aspx) the web page to a string formatted like:

```
javascript:{ 
    // Your code here
}

javascript:(function(){ 
    // You can also use this if you want to load your script as a module
})()
```

This will run the javascript immediately. Not exactly what you want but it is useful especially if you want to hide your scripts in the dom

Answer (score 0):

Your main purpose is to inject your javascript into the webpage. So, you actually want to develop a custom IE extension plug-in. My suggestion is to use the [Browser Helper Object](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/149258/Inject-HTML-and-JavaScript-into-an-existing-page-w) method which runs within IE and offers additional services. Implementation is possible with [ATL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250489(v=vs.85).aspx) or with [plain c++](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37044/Writing-a-BHO-in-Plain-C). There is also another simple example like [How to inject javascript code into WebBrowser in Windows Forms applications](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/How-to-inject-javascript-f3970459#content)

Example :

```
 System::Void MyForm::webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs^  e)  
{ 
 HtmlElement^ headElement = webBrowser1->Document->GetElementsByTagName("head")[0]; 
 HtmlElement^ scriptElement = webBrowser1->Document->CreateElement("script");  
 IHTMLScriptElement^ element = (IHTMLScriptElement^)scriptElement->DomElement;  
 element->text = "function sayHello() { alert('hello') }";  
 headElement->AppendChild(scriptElement); 
 webBrowser1->Document->InvokeScript("sayHello"); 
}
```

I think this is what you want!

Comment: The technology I am using in this app is similar to that of a BHO. The primary difference is that instead of registering as a plugin I get access to all of the COM objects manually. So it's as if I have a BHO I just need to know how it would inject usable javascript.